# Changing width using jQuery .css() and em

Tags: jquery, width

I need to change the width of an div using jQuery.

When I use the following, it works:

```
$('#footer').css('width', '100%');
$('#footer').css('width', '-=239');
```

When I use this, it works:

```
$('#footer').css('width', '100%');
$('#footer').css('width', '-=239px');
```

But when I use this it doesn't do anything:

```
$('#footer').css('width', '100%');
$('#footer').css('width', '-=21em');
```

Is there a way to make jQuery work with `em`? or to calculate `em` to `px` and set a variable for example and subtract that value?

edit: thanks everybody for correcting my spelling and code!

Comment: OKey figured it out. i had given the footer an left-border of 21em, and would like to correct for that so i subtracted 21em. but for some reason the 21em subtraction was only a few pixels. so i didn't noticed it. i needed to subtract 252em to fix this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i tried it and it is working i think you should check your code i have checked it in all browser and it is working fine px and em both working well you can use this code put this code in a dummy page and u can see this works

```
<style>
#footer{
background: black;
height:50px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#footer').css('width', '100%');
    $('#footer').css('width', '-=210em');
});
</script>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for testing, and answering.
Could it have something to do with div's positioning?

Comment: jQuery is interpreting your `-=210em` as `210px`